# SecurityVoter based on class instead of object

Tags: symfony

It's a question about [SecurityVoter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html).

With Symfony 2.6, you can create simpler security voters to check if user have specifics permissions on a object:

```
protected function isGranted($attribute, $object, $user = null)
{
    switch ($attribute) {
        case self::VIEW:
            return $object->getAuthor() === $user;
        case self::EDIT:
            return $object->getAuthor() === $user && time() - $object->getAddedAt()->getTimestamp() <= TicketMessage::PERMIT_EDIT_GAP;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

That works. But what if I want to check an attributes based on the class instead of a object ? For example, a 'create' permissions for creating a new object that not exists for the moment.

Code sample:

```
is_granted('create', 'AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity')
```

or:

```
is_granted('create', 'AppBundle:Entity')
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding how the voters work - they need something to check the permissions against.  At worst you could just instantiate a new version of the object without any values and use that?

Comment: I started link this yes with an empty object instanciation. But I have to check this righ also on twig, and I don't have this object on template...

Comment: Where do you have the information about what a user can do on a class ?

Answer (score -1):

Please, read the documentation on [Symfony Best Practicles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html) and [Symfony Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html) for better understanding the concepts of Symfony. 
If you really need to check permissions based only on class attributes, then the decision is going to be **constant**. So, the recommended way to control your application's logic is described in [Symfony Best Practicles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html):

> **Best Practice**: Use constants to define configuration options that
>   rarely change.

As you can see, there are two recommended ways of doing what you want:

- use constants (For example you can define some constants in your
  custom `YourBundle\SecurityManager`)
- use `parameters.yml` for    configuration

Comment: I know the security best practices but I don't really see how this help me for my use case... Can you provide a example of your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of trying to vote on whether a create route should be accessible or not...